# import serial using wrong version of PySerial

Tags: serial, pi-zero

I have a Pi Zero that needs to use PySerial 3.4.
When I run `pip freeze`, it says `pyserial==3.4`.

However, in the actual program (Python 3.4.2), when I do `import serial` and `print(serial.VERSION)`, it says `2.6`, which was the previous version installed, and pyserial 3.4 methods do not work.

Before updating PySerial, I also just updated Raspbian OS, so that might have something to do with it, but I am not very sure.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I should have used `pip3` to install instead of `pip` since I was using Python 3. `pip3 freeze` was showing `pyserial==2.6` but after `sudo pip3 install pyserial --upgrade` it worked.